# Laravel 5 Quiz Project

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.1

This is probably more of a conceptual question but I am trying to find the best way to make a view that displays one quiz question at a time and checks the answer.

Currently my MySQL table has the following columns: id, category_id, quiz_question, answer_one, answer_two, answer_three, correct_answer.

My controller uses the following to get the quiz questions:

```
$quizzes = Quiz::where('category_id',$category_id)->simplePaginate(1);
```

In my view, I go through the process of doing the asnwer ordering manually

```
{{$quiz->quiz_question }}

<a onclick="this.innerHTML='Wrong'">{{ $quiz->answer_one }}</a>
<a onclick="this.innerHTML='Right'">{{ $quiz->correct_answer }}</a>
<a onclick="this.innerHTML='Wrong'">{{ $quiz->answer_two }}</a>...etc.
```

and was probably just going to use JavaScript/JQuery to check for the right answer.

Conceptually this feels like a pretty bad way to do this and I am still not sure how to randomize the order of the answers if they are from the same DB table like this. Overall is there a better way to go about this (Display 1 quiz question, and display answers in random order, check without a DB query)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not keep the answers on the client side in any form.**

Instead, just get the questions and paginate it on the client side. If you absolutely need to validate answers one by one, then fire up AJAX requests.

Or you can just let the person attempt the whole quiz and post the questions with users' answers and validate them on the server side. Then you return the result/score/answers.

Regarding your query about checking without DB query, you shouldn't do it. If you absolutely need it then save answers in an object, rather than in the DOM. Again, it can't be any more "not recommended".

**Edit:**

You should first divide it into these tables. You can't randomize the order of display of the options without a hack from the first table.

And don't name the columns like answer_one, answer_two, answer_three, correct_answer. In this manner the only way to recognize the answer in by the column name `correct_answer`. Column name shouldn't give a hint about the correct answer. It should be stored somewhere else.

1. questions

   ```
   id
   question - the question body
   ```
2. categories

   ```
   id
   category - name of the category
   ```
3. question_categories (one question may belong to multiple categories)

   ```
   id
   question_id
   category_id
   ```
4. options

   ```
   id
   question_id
   option - option text
   ```
5. answers

   ```
   id
   question_id
   option_id
   ```

Now what you do is you randomize the order of options

```
$questions = Question::where('category_id', $category_id)->
             with(['options' => function ($query) {
               $query->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'));
             }])
             ->get();
```

To randomly order the options we used `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Now you just send the `option_id` and can check if it is the correct answer on the server side.

## Edit - 27th March

You can use the following models.

1. Question
2. QuestionCategory
3. Category
4. Option
5. Answer

You can use the following relationships.

1. Question belongsTo QuestionCategory
2. QuestionCategory belongsTo Category
3. Question hasMany Option
4. Question hasOne Answer

But creating a QuestionCategory model doesn't really scale well. So if you don't want to do that you can use Polymorphic relationships. You can use category table to store basically all types of categories, not just question categories. In that case, you need to modify the `categories` tables to add the type of taxonomy. If you don't understand any of this polymorphic relationship thing, please find it in the official Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Ok thanks, do you by any chance know the best way to randomize the answers if they are coming from the same table like this?

Comment: @AnthonyPham - You can't do the randomizing in the query directly if they are from the same table. You need to do it in application level e.g. `shuffle()` in PHP. For a better solution, please refer to the edited section above.

Comment: @AnthonyPham can you help me breakdown on how to tackle this on model ? Model belongs to which ?

Comment: @user2040026 I have done few quiz apps. When I do, I did stored all the answers in Answers table (id, text, que_id, is_correct). I saw ur suggestion on few places. I hope to go with this. But, I need to know, what is the advantage when doing this?

Comment: @SurajMalinga This is called database normalization. We are basically decomposing the table structures and reducing the redundancy. In your case, the is_correct column is redundant. This doesn't matter much if you are a single developer, but as you work with others they will better understand your architecture. And may be when you see your project after 5 years you will better understand what's going on.