# How to get JSON data in this format using Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-8

I tried to save data to the MySQL database and successfully saved data.
I want to get JSON data in this formate

```
{
   "response_code":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "question":"Here is my question?",
         "correct_answer":"Correct Answer",
         "incorrect_answers":[
            "wrong_1",
            "wrong_2",
            "wrong_3"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But I am getting my JSON data in this format

```
{
   "response_code":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "question":"Here is my question?",
         "correct_answer":"right_ans",
         "incorrect_answers_1":"wrong_1",
         "incorrect_answers_2":"wrong_2",
         "incorrect_answers_3":"wrong_3",
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my MySql database
[image]

Please suggest to me how can I get my JSON Data in my desired format? If you want more files or information then I will edit my questions.

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id"=>$this->id,
            "right_ans" =>$this->right_ans,
            "incorrect_answers_1" =>$this->wrong_1,
            "incorrect_answers_1" =>$this->wrong_2,
            "incorrect_answers_1" =>$this->wrong_3,
            "created"=>$this->created_at,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code on how you generate the current format.

Comment: This is achievable but the DB design is incorrect. There should be a one to many relationship between questions and a new options table. This design would have made it so much simpler for your use case and also provides flexibility to increase number of options and also number of correct answers for a question.

Comment: @jrcamatog I have added resources file

Comment: @nice_dev can you please suggest to me any tutorials that how can I achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236545/laravel-5-quiz-project

Comment: There are tons of tutorials though https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+online+quiz+project&client=ms-unknown&biw=360&bih=512&ei=SEBrYL-OGpPF4-EPl_WJyAo&oq=laravel+quiz+table&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAEYADIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1AAWABgl0loAHABeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQjAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating array like this. It will return json as expected.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
   return [
      "id"=>$this->id,
      "right_ans" =>$this->right_ans,
      "incorrect_answers" => array (
             $this->wrong_1,
             $this->wrong_2,
             $this->wrong_3),
      "created"=>$this->created_at,
    ];
}
```